# Selenium webdriver ruby assertTextPresent equivalent

Tags: ruby, selenium, webdriver

I cannot figure out what the assertTextPresent equivalent for seleniums webdriver is. I found several answers for java, but none for ruby. Does anybody have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Text assertions are not part of WebDriver, but you can do:

```
assert driver.find_element(:tag_name, "body").text.include?(str)
```

Comment: undefined method `assert' for main:Object (NoMethodError)

Comment: This assumes you are using a standard testing framework, such as TestUnit or MiniTest that includes the assert method. This is pretty much a requirement for any sort of actual testing in Ruby.

Answer (score 1):

selenium-webdriver does not come with an inbuilt assertion library, you need to have an additional one to cater to you assertion needs.

Now coming to language which is ruby then the best one would be to use rspec.

How do you use that :
1) Install rspec of put it in your Gemfile and do a bundle install
2) require 'rspec' in your framework
3) use rspec-expectations

`expect(actual-text).to include(expected-text)`

Here is full single script example

```
require 'selenium-webdriver'
require 'rspec'
include RSpec::Matchers

def assert_text_present(expected_text)
  expect(driver.find_element(:tag_name=>'body').text.include(expected_text)).to be true
end

driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome
driver.get("https://rubygems.org/gems/testnow")
assert_text_present("Kaushal")
```

Additionally you can define this method `def assert_text_present` in a utility or a helper file of your framework and use it repeatedly when required.

Note: If you put this method in a framework, you can use the include matcher directly (`expect(driver.find_element(:tag_name=>'body').text).to include(expected_text)`)

Hope it helps!!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend rspec-expectations

> https://github.com/rspec/rspec-expectations

It is realy comprehensive assertion "library".

In this case you could use following matcher:

> expect(actual_text).to eq(expected_text)